# Trying to get SSH with public key (no password) + google authenticator working on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, two-factor, google-authenticator

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 (with OpenSSH 6.6 and libpam-google-authenticator 20130529-2).

I'm trying to set up SSH logins where the public key authenticates (without a password) and a user is prompted for a code from Google's Authenticator.

Following/adapting these instructions has gotten me a password prompt as well as a Google Auth prompt:

- https://scottlinux.com/2013/06/02/use-google-authenticator-for-two-factor-ssh-authentication-in-linux/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Google_Authenticator and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Two-factor_authentication_and_public_keys
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication

I've installed the package, edited my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/pam.d/ssh` files

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods  publickey,keyboard-interactive
UsePAM yes
```

and at the bottom of `/etc/pam.d/ssh`:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok # (I want to give everyone a chance to set up their 2FA before removing "nullok")
```

I know PAM is order dependent, but is `sshd_config` also?

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Have got it working well, first did:

```
apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator
```

In `/etc/pam.d/sshd` I have changed/added the following lines (at the top):

```
# @include common-auth
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

And in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Works well and I now receive a "Verification code" prompt after authentication with public key. I am not sure how I would allow authentication with password+token OR key+token, as I have now effectively removed the password authentication method from PAM.

Using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-19-generic x86_64) with ssh -v : OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: So, for posterity's sake, I realized my problem. I also had tried `PasswordAuthentication no`, but that wasn't it. The problem is/was that I had/have `ControlMaster auto` and `ControlPath` directives in my ~/.ssh/config file. I wanted to make sure I didn't lock myself out, so I would always leave an SSH session open. Since my computer would just reuse them, I always got in without the system asking for a token. I marked your answer as correct, since someone following it would indeed get a working setup. Thanks!

Comment: I am also interested in learning how to setup password+token OR key+token authentication.

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7. I have `PasswordAuthentication no`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`, `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`, and `UsePAM yes` in `sshd_config`. It validates my key _and then_ asks me for my Google Authenticator token _**and then also**_ asks me for my password. Makes me do all three—can't skip any of them. I've also tried `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam` as suggested by the man page, but that didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickWilliams I was having the same issue. What fixed it for me was that I needed to commend out the `@include common-auth` line that the answers shows. I just thought it was a comment for the `pam_google_authenticator` line in /etc/pam.d/sshd at first.

Comment: Thank you! My solution wasn't exactly the same (I needed to comment out `auth       substack     password-auth`), but your comment solved my problem!

Comment: @NickWilliams Nick, thanks so much.  Your solution about `auth substack password-auth` helped save me from more searching.  CentOS 7

Comment: https://sysconfig.org.uk/two-factor-authentication-with-ssh.html

Answer (score 11):

Linus Kendall's answer should work on older systems, but on newer Linux machines it is problematic; on my arch linux based webserver that configuration results in pam asking for my authenticator code and my password after receiving my ssh key (i.e. I need all 3).

A simpler solution that prevents this problem and that should work on every system is to change the entry in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to:

```
auth sufficient pam_google_authenticator.so
```

And then to make the same edits to ``/etc/ssh/sshd` that Linus mentioned:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
PasswordAuthentication no
```

That should ask you for your authenticator token after the server accepts your public key. It should not ask for your password.

As a side note, if you wish to have an sftp user account, you will probably need to bypass google authenticator in order to get it to work. Here is a suggestion of how to do that securely using an sftp jail. In `etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User ftp-user
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  AuthenticationMethods password
  ChrootDirectory /path/to/ftp/dir
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

You will need to make the permissions on /path/to/ftp/dir root write only (e.g. `chown root:root /path/to/ftp/dir`, `chmod 755 /path/to/ftp/dir`. All of the parents above that directory also need secure permissions. The way I usually do this is by making the chroot directory `/home/shared/user`, creating a directory in there (e.g. 'data') and then mounting whatever directory I want to share like this: `sudo mount -o bind /path/to/ftp/dir /home/shared/user/data`

If you follow all of those steps, you will have public key + google authenticator login for your ssh users, and a functional password protected sftp account for data transfer.

Comment: This works great. And since for some reason I just don't feel comfortable commenting out common-auth, this was more ideal than Linus's solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! wasted a night debugging ssh, wondering why I still have to type password after pubkey+authcode……

Answer (score 8):

I was finally able to get this working by placing `auth [success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=die] pam_google_authenticator.so nullok` at the top of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

According to the [pam.d man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d):

- `success=done` means that if Google Authenticator signs off, no more authentication will be performed, meaning no additional password prompt.
- `default=die` means that if Google Authenticator rejects the login attempt, authentication will immediately fail, skipping the password prompt.

So `[success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=die]` is sort of a mix between the `sufficient` and `requisite` control values, since we want behavior from both: if success, terminate immediately (sufficient), and if failure, also terminate immediately (requisite).

Note that the `nullok` argument to pam_google_authenticator.so means that if a `~/.google_authenticator` file is not found for a user, public-key authentication proceeds as normal. This is useful if I want to lock down only a subset of my accounts with 2FA.

Comment: I've tried this, however if I don't have a .google_authenticator file then the keyboard-interactive authentication fails, I think because no other PAM module approves the login.